# Is Blatt-Weisskopf's treatment of nuclear forces still relevant today?

Tags: nuclear-physics, exchange-interaction

As in the title, is the treatment of nuclear forces by Blatt and Weisskopf, as in Chapter III of "Theoretical Nuclear Physics", still relevant today, especially with regard to the role of exchange forces? I haven't read the whole chapter yet; having no previous knowledge on the subject I need to know how much of it is still considered valid.